# how i can use ListOfArrays in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have been working mainly in JAVA but now I need to program some small things in kotlin. Among other things I am trying to convert the result of a database query into a list of array. The result of the database query has 4 columns, the number of rows I can not predict.

I have tried the following:

```
var output: mutableList<List<String>>
var output = mutableListOf<String>()
var output = mutableListOf<ArrayList>
List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>()
```

What I would like to do is this:

```
output.add(arrayOf("Field1", "Filed2", "Field3", "Field4"))
```

It can't be that hard, can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In kotlin you should use lists where you can. What you are trying to create is:

```
    val output = mutableListOf<List<String>>()
    output.add(listOf("Field1", "Filed2", "Field3", "Field4"))
```

If you are iterating through some other list to create your data for output you could do something like:

```
    val otherList = listOf<String>("a", "b", "v")
    val output = otherList.map { otherListData ->
        listOf(otherListData + 1, otherListData + 2, otherListData + 3, otherListData + 4)
    }
```

In which case you would only have immutable lists.

Answer (score 2):

A list of arrays can be expressed as `List<Array<T>>`.

So if you want a mutable list to which you can add arrays of strings, simply do:

```kotlin
var output = mutableListOf<Array<String>>()
output.add(arrayOf("Field1", "Filed2", "Field3", "Field4"))
```

That being said, why do you want to use arrays? It's generally more convenient to work with lists, unless you're constrained by another API.